# How to read file from other app's sandbox in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, sandbox

A text input view in my app supports drag & drop of images to insert them. When user drops an image in the input view, I can get the absolute path of the file, then display it as an attachment. However, when the user drags an image which is originally located in another app's sandbox, my app seems having insufficient permission to read it.

Is there any way to read files from other app's sandbox? (Such as asking user for permission or other tricks)

Comment: I believe that should work.  What errors are you getting?

Comment: After failure of the drag & drop action, I can see `sandboxd: ([PID]) AppName(PID) deny file-read-data` in the console.

Comment: It seems to be my own problem when handling drag & drop action. I can not use attributed string directly to show the image.